# Joke Website / Funny Website repercussions

Tags: negligence, damages, administrative-law, civil-legal-system

I have made a funny site not really trying to be serious, which may involve hitting your head on a wall. I state this is a joke, and not meant to be taken seriously. But I'm just trying to cover my bases, and make sure I'm not open to a law suit.

It's not currently available to the public, but I would like it to be.

I am located in California, if that helps.

The terms listed are as follows:

> **TERMS & CONDITIONS**
>
> **Please note:**
>
> This is not medical advice.
>
> This is not meant to be taken literally.
>
> Any bodily harm that may come of this is at the sole discretion of the "idiot" taking this literally.
>
> This is a joke.
>
> Also may not relive stress, and instead cause head ache, or severe brain injury.

Am I susceptible to claims of damages if someone takes the gag/joke seriously and hurts themselves as a result? What can I do to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Pardon the pun, but you must be joking.

There is no possibility that a lawsuit based on someone following obviously self-destructive advice on an obviously humorous website would succeed.